# Retrieving SelectedItem from ComboBox error

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am trying to retrieve the selected value of a combo box but I am having a weird problem occurring.

I have tried:

`myCombo.SelectedItem.ToString()` and I am getting back the value:

```
System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: myValue.
```

I have then tried:

```
ComboBoxItem item = ((ComboBoxItem)myCombo.selectedItem);
item.content.toString();
```

This works fine if selected index is 0 or 1. However if any of the other indexes are selected it displays the exception:

> InvalidCastException was unhandled Unable to case object of type
>   'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem'

The only difference between index 0 and 1 and the others are, index 0 and 1 are added manually via the XAML whereas the others are added programatically from a database query like below:

```
string myValue = reader["my_table_column"].toString();
myCombo.Items.Add(myValue);
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

**UPDATE**
As Wayne Tanner requested below is a snippet of the XAML for the combo box

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,6,0,0" Name="cboIVRGroup" SelectedIndex="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="143" SelectionChanged="cboIVRGroup_SelectionChanged">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="All IVRs" />
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Unassigned IVRs" />
                </ComboBox>r the combo box
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programmatically added ones may be added as XAML does:

```
string myValue = reader["my_table_column"].toString();
ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem();
item.Content = myValue;
myCombo.Items.Add(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the SelectedValue property to get the actual selected string.

Comment: Thanks for your help but doing it that way now works in the reverse to my question. I.e. index 0 and 1 get System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem MyXAMLItem whereas the other ones get the correct value.

Comment: Can you post a snippit of the XAML? It sounds like something isn't quite right with it.

Comment: In your XAML, if you add SelectedValuePath="Content" to the ComboBox control, the SelectedValue property will then have the actual string value of the selected item.